# Induction compatible pans not working on induction stove-top

Tags: equipment, pan, induction

I just purchased a set of "induction ready" pans from All-Clad. Found [here](https://www.all-clad.com/Cookware/B1%C2%AE-Nonstick-2-Pack-Fry-Pan-Set-8%22-%26-10%22/p/2100085503).

However, to my dismay when I got them home, they wouldn't work! My stove makes a kind of clicking noise when I try to use cookware that's too small or not quite placed inside the cooking zone, and that's what I heard with these, although according to my range's manual they are the correct size.

I have a Samsung Range, [NE599N1PBSR/AC](https://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/NE599N1PBSR/AC)

I can return them so it's not a huge deal, but I'd like to know why they don't work. Is it because their bottoms aren't flat? They have kind of grooves going towards the center, maybe to help distribute heat?

Comment: One of the comments on the product page suggests that there are embedded plated to make them ‘induction-ready’ but that they are undersized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely there isn't enough ferromagnetic material in the base of the pan or it's of an incorrect dimension.
If your range is very sensitive it won't detect the pan and thus won't activate.

I myself had a very sensitive induction range which would already deactivate if the pan was lifted a millimetre off the plate or if the pan size was mismatched. (Try using an induction wok on that.)

The only advice I can give is: if buying pots and pans, to be used on an induction range, in the shops take a magnet with you. Place the magnet on the base of the pot/pan and make sure it has a strong magnetic pull. If there isn't any or it's very weak I'd skip the pot/pan and try a different kind. This won't necessarily help with mismatched dimensions of the ferromagnetic material but at least it will give you an idea, you can also try the magnet on different spots on the base to attempt to check the dimensions.
It's not a fool-proof method but at least it will give you a better idea of what will work and what won't.

Also I'd go for high-quality pots and pans (I don't know/have any experience with the All-Clad brand so I couldn't say if they aren't good quality pans) with a thick base as this will usually mean there is more ferromagnetic material in the based and will also help distribute the heat better in the pan.

Comment: You should probably check the edges as well as the centre when using your magnet